# Why does MySQL not include the primary key in a unique index constraint when inserting with the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

I have a table that has an auto-incrementing primary key and it also has a unique index with two other columns.  The problem is that when I insert a record, it does not include the primary key as part of the Entity Keys so if I don't change the other fields in the unique index, it complains of a duplicate entry.  The only way I can get it to work is if I add the primary key to the unique index, but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correct if you have an unique index which include both the primary key and two other columns?

If this is true, that is a wrong way to do it. Since one of the columns is the primary key, which always will be unique, those two other columns will never matter on the unique index.

Can you post your table definition?

Comment: The unique index does not include the primary key, but I was curious if the primary key was used in conjunctionw with the unique index when inserting into a database.

Comment: You can add as many unique indexes you want in a table, they are still just unique on what you define. If you have three columns, one primary, one string and one integer, you can create one unique index on both string and integer columns, but they will not check eachother for uniqueness. So you can add (1, "hi", 1) or (2, "yo", 2) into them. But you can't then add (1, "no", 3) since it will break primary index, or (3, "hi", 3) since it will break string index, or (3, "yes", 1) since it will break integer index.